# Python iterar Json con nombre de atributos diferentes

Tags: python, json

Buen día, estoy trabajando con la API de Cisco Meraki, mi problema es que necesito iterar y guardar los datos que vienen de un json como el siguiente:

```
    [
  {
    "name":"My AP",
    "lat":37.4180951010362,
    "lng":-122.098531723022,
    "serial":"Q2XX-XXXX-XXXX",
    "mac":"00:11:22:33:44:55:66",
    "model":"MR34",
    "address":"1600 Pennsylvania Ave",
    "lanIp":"1.2.3.4"
    "tags":" recently-added ",
    "networkId":"N_1234",
    "beaconIdParams": {
      "uuid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "major": 5,
      "minor": 3,
    }
  }
]
```

facilmente puedo obtener datos como networkId al iterar los datos del siguiente modo:

```
for each in api_data:
        print(each["networkId"])}
```

pero el problema es que atributos como beaconIdParams y lanIp no se presentan en todos los arreglos o aparecen con otros nombres (por ejemplo lanIp puede cambiar por wan1Ip o en algunos casos beaconIdParams no aparece) así que quisiera saber el modo de poner condiciones para que me devuelva los valores de esos atributos.
Espero poder recibir su ayuda, Gracias.

Comment: Hola, creo que ayudaría un poco saber qué uso le vas a dar o cómo los vas a procesar porque no creo que solo lo quieras imprimir en pantalla, ¿o sí?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes intentar lo siguiente:

```
for each in api_data:
    beaconIdParams = each.get('beaconIdParams', None)
```

Asumiendo que iteras sobre una lista de diccionarios; el método get te permite evitar un "KeyError", definiendo un valor por defecto, en este ejemplo el valor por defecto sería None.

Comment: Perfecto, es exactamente lo que requeria, la unica duda que me queda es como ahora acceder los valores del arreglo beaconIdParams por separado, pero creo poder resolver eso por mi mismo, muchisimas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Para acceder a los elementos beaconIdParams, puedes hace lo siguiente: sí beaconIdParams no es None, entonces accedes a los elementos por su "key", si te sirvió podrías puntear la respuesta :D